# TFS adding comments to discussion

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, comments

I'm migrating cards from LeanKit and I need to add comments to Discussion in cards on TFS.
How can I add programitcally comment to WorkItem as other user?
Is it possible?
I found only adding comments by History property but as a logged in user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default we can only add comments by the logged in user.

However you could add the comments to discussion with another user using the REST API to update the value of `System.ChangedBy` field with `bypassRules` enabled:

Below sample for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$workitemID = "26",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "token/Password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
write-host $WorkitemType

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.History",
    "value": "Comment here"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.ChangedBy",
    "value": "user@oxxx.com"
  }
]
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemID)?bypassRules=true&api-version=2.2"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

The "value": "user@oxxx.com" can be valid user id (guid) or user email of another user.

Answer (score 0):

You can add comments to the discussion as another user only if you log in with his credentials:

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("anotherUserName", "password");
TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("serverUrl"), cred);
_tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

After you authenticated like another user you add text to History field and you will see the text on the discussion as a logged in another user.